# Stop route when all messages are filtered

Tags: java, xquery, apache-camel

I have a batch route that consumes XML files from a folder. It filters, transforms and finally saves a grouped document to disk. As this is a batch route, I require it to be shut down after a single polling of the sourcefolder, which is what the RouteTerminator is for in the code below. (It calls `stopRoute()` and `removeRoute()` on `camelContext` with `routeID`.)

```
from("file:" + sourcePath)
    .filter().xquery("//DateTime > xs:dateTime('2013-05-07T23:59:59')")
    .filter().xquery("//DateTime < xs:dateTime('2013-05-09T00:00:00')")
    .aggregate(constant(true))
        .completionFromBatchConsumer()
        .groupExchanges()
    .to("xquery:" + xqueryPath)
    .to("file:" + targetPath)
    .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        new RouteTerminator(routeID, exchange.getContext()).start();
                    }
                })
    .end();
```

This correctly closes the route after a single file collection and after repeating the process in `onException` it also gracefully closes the route when an exception is thrown. Unfortunately, if the route filters out every Exchange, it never reaches the processor. Exchanges are instead dropped during the filter and the route remains open.

I thought to move the filter inside the `aggregate` call as this might keep the route going until the end, but this method won't accept XQuery filters. XPath is not an option as it does not support dateTime comparisons.

How can I force the entire route to stop in this case?

Comment: I've found a very hacky way to do this by inserting one bogus record into the exchange in a bean and then filtering this record out in the XQuery that I call but I'd obviously prefer a cleaner approach.

Comment: Instead of using filter, have you contemplated on using CHOICE predicate

Comment: @Joe2013 I had but it didn't work very well. After your comment I tried again and now have a solution where I call `setHeader` to set a `Filtered` header. Unfortunately I can't seem to break out of the `choice` to use it as a simple switch/case so I have to route both the `.when()` and `.otherwise()` to the same second direct route. In that route I then aggregate and call a basic merge bean that builds a Document out of every Exchange and adds it to a GenericFile if the header matches. It seems like there should be an easier way to simply set a header based on an xquery though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried again and now have a solution where I call setHeader to set a Filtered header.
>
> Unfortunately I can't seem to break out of the choice to use it as a simple switch/case so I have to route both the .when() and .otherwise() to the same second direct route.
>
> In that route I then aggregate and call a basic merge bean that builds a Document out of every Exchange and adds it to a GenericFile if the header matches. It seems like there should be an easier way to simply set a header based on an xquery though...